# Is this possible: document.form.array[i].value?

Tags: javascript

I have not found an answer to this online nor does the debugger tell me enough to understand what alternatives I might use.  **Is it possible to post the "fill" value into the text boxes using an array to the effect I'm trying to use below?**  I could write document.form.a.value = fill; document.form.b.value = fill; etc., but a loop and array seems more more simplified and efficient.
Here's a simplified version of the code that's giving me an error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postData() {
var fill = 0.0;
var txtBoxLetter = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
    for (var i = 0; i < txtBoxLetter.length; i++)   {
        document.form.txtBoxLetter[i].value = fill; // Error on this line
    }
}
</script>

<form name="form" method="" action="">
<input type="text" name="a" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="b" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="c" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="d" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="e" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="f" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="g" size="1" readonly="true">
<input type="text" name="h" size="1" readonly="true">
// etc.
</form>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDN form elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements)

```
document.form.elements[ txtBoxLetter[i] ].value = fill;
```

Comment: Exactly the syntax I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use square brackets to use a variable as a property name...

```js
document.forms[0][txtBoxLetter[i]].value = fill;
```

---

It's the same thing you're doing when you do...

```
txtBoxLetter[i]
```

---

If you actually have a-z, you could skip the Array...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++)   {
    document.forms[0][String.fromCharCode(i + 97)].value = fill;
}
```